# MS Exchange 2000 - move entire mail store to another server

Tags: exchange

I am in the situation that I have to replace an old server running MS Exchange 2000 server.
This is running within a Active Directory domain consisting of, apart from that old server, a few Windows Server 2003 machines.

As a first step I want to create a VM on a new server, using again MS Exchange 2000, no upgrade at that stage. I have to however move the entire mail store to the new server, and that old server hasn't got much extra disk space, nor is it fast.

Can I just make a standard Exchange backup on the old server and restore it into a fresh install on the new VM?
I have been searching around but could not find advice on this really.

I could potentially use the imapsync program, synchronizing both Exchange mail stores via IMAP. Anyone knows if that is going to work, or are there specific points to be taken care of? Would that work with Active Directory?

If not, any advice?

Comment: any reason why you don't want a newer exchange version or just p2v the old server?

Comment: Right now I just want to get this off that very old server - cannot afford to have this thing fail. Don't currently have licenses for a newer version. e

Comment: p2v sounds good - but currently running Citrix XenServer, and the p2v is miserable for Windows Servers. Woudn't trust it.